# How to align data and transpose it in google sheets using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data laid out as shown below and in Image 1:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 225566 | dash |
| 225566 | slash |
| 225566 | backspace |
| 221166 | enter |
| 221166 | delete |
| 221166 | shift |

I want the data arranged as below and Image 2 using Google Apps Script:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 225566 | dash | slash | backspace |
| 221166 | enter | delete | shift |

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  **1)** Solve the problem with a formula in the spreadsheet. **2)** Try to adapt that formula as a Google Apps Script. **3)** If you run into problems, share with us what you tried and where it failed.  Since you are new to Stack Overflow, be sure to take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour "https://stackoverflow.com/tour") and also review [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask")

Comment: Of course, someone might just [write some code from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76212339/) for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it works for you.

```html
function separateWords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:B").getValues();
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var numberReference = data[i][0];
    var wordAssociated = data[i][1];

    var filaExisting = results.findIndex(function(row) {
      return row[0] === numberReference;
    });

    if (filaExisting !== -1) {
      results[filaExisting].push(wordAssociated);
    } else {
      results.push([numberReference, wordAssociated]);
    }
  }

  var numColumns = results.reduce(function(max, row) {
    return Math.max(max, row.length);
  }, 0);

  // Make sure that all rows have the same number of columns
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    while (results[i].length < numColumns) {
      results[i].push("");
    }
  }

  var rangeResults = sheet.getRange(1, 3, results.length, numColumns);
  rangeResults.setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked, but what if i want to add third row to the main data

Answer (score -1):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let obj = { pA: [] };
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      obj[r[0]] = [r[0], r[1]];
      obj.pA.push(r[0]);
    } else {
      obj[r[0]].push(r[1])
    }
  });
  obj.pA.forEach(p => sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, obj[p].length).setValues([obj[p]]));//rows need not have the same number of columns
}
```